# Как построить матрицы по данным отношениям?

Tags: математика, дискретная-математика

Есть 2 вида отношений `a = {(x, y) ∈ R^2 | x + y = 0}` и `b = {(x, y) ∈ N^2 | y = x^2}`. Как по ним построить матрицы?
Я правильно понимаю, что в случае `a` - это будет матрица из нулей, в которой на местах x и y будут единицы, если x + y = 0, а в случае `b` - это матрица из нулей, в которой на местах x и y будут единицы, если y = x^2?

```
Пример b

  x 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
y +------------------
1 | 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 | 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
3 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
4 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Но как строить такие матрицы? Они ведь бесконечные. Как мне, например, перемножить 2 матрицы по отношению `b`?

Comment: О каких матрица речь?

Comment: Обычно матрица - конечная таблица. Какие матрицы на `N^2` и `R^2` (!) ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy матрицы бинарных отношений

Comment: Для конечных можеств это имеет смысл. А для `N` и `R` - нет. Вы можете построить график отношения. Называть его матрицей не надо.

Comment: Так, предыдущий вопрос вы уже удалили, но это такой же непонятный. Попробуйте всё-таки рассказать задачу, потому что пока совершенно непонятно при чём тут матрицы.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а как построить график, он же по идее тоже получится бесконечным

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, вопрос удалил, из-за того, что с большей частью разобрался. Задание состоит в том, чтобы зная отношение, посчитать: обратное `a^-1`, композицию начального отношения с обратным `a * a^-1` и наоборот - композицию обратного с начальным `a^-1 * a`

Comment: А зачем вам для этого матрицы? Просто посчитайте по определениям и все.

Comment: @EzikBro а как это сделать? По определению `p^−1 = {(y, x) | (x, y) ∈ p}`. В случае `a` (из вопроса) как мне поменять x и y местами и что это даст? А, или `a^-1 = {(x, y) ∈ R^2 | x + y ≠ 0}`? Но что делать с композицией?

Comment: График - понятие абстрактное. Его не надо строить, его достаточно описать. Иногда кусок графика рисуют на бумаге, чтобы задействовать воображение.